# Why does T-1000 have three arms?

Tags: the-terminator-series, behind-the-scenes, terminator-2-judgment-day

Several times throughout the helicopter chase scene in *Terminator 2*, [the T-1000 is shown with three to four hands](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/47714/51226). Why?

[image]

There are three reasons that can think of for this.

1. In-universe, he is capable of growing multiple hands when necessary. We see that his form is nebulous, so this is possible. However, if he had this ability all along, you would think he would use it more often.
2. It's an unintentional error on the part of the film's creators.
3. The film's creators wanted him to use a gun and fly a helicopter at the same time and thought that giving him extra arms was the only way to do this. Maybe they hoped nobody would notice?

Are any of these, or something else, the reason?

Comment: I've watched the movie a bazillion times and never noticed the extra hands! My +1 for spotting that and for the hand-drawn arrows!

Comment: Same here.  *T2* is one of my all-time favourite films and I never noticed this.  After nearly 30 years, I've learned something new about this film.

Comment: How could anyone accidentally film someone with too many arms?

Comment: Why doesn't it always have four arms? Infiltrators have two arms.... Target acquisition is complete, execute function: engage target at all expense. - Target lost. Restart function; infiltration. Model: 'Sarah Conner'. Say: "John?!?"

Answer (score 25):

The multiple hands were intentional by the film makers. James Cameron actually discusses it in the commentary on the T2 Ultimate edition DVD. He points out that in order to fly the helicopter and fire a weapon at the same time the T1000 has grown a second set of arms. So the answer is yes to the first point you make, (possibly he does not deploy additional arms before this as he has a need to pass unnoticed as a human to locate his target)  no to the second point, it was definitely intentional, and yes to the third point.

Comment: If I can find the relevant clip on Youtube I will update this to the answer. Or, if any other users on the site know where the clip is go ahead and add it. Thank you.

Comment: For the record this is not the same commentary as appeared on the Extreme edition DVD which features Cameron talking with William Wisher, rather this is a more general commentary with comments from multiple cast and crew, I've searched but not found it on Youtube. If its out there and someone has a link it would be great to add to the answer.

Comment: Here you go: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJofF1yitB8 T-1000 with four arms [Robert Patrick Commentary] [TERMINATOR 2: Judgment Day]

Comment: @Zwyx nice find! very much obliged! Thank you!